# Jquery change values mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mouseover

I wrote this code but it doesn't work:

JavaScript:

```
$(function() { 
    var menu_h_number=5

    for (i=1; i<=menu_h_number; i++)
    {
        $(".web_header_mb_"+i).show(1000);

        $(".web_header_mb_"+i).css("background", "#FF0000");

        $(".web_header_mb_"+i).hover(function () 
        {
            $(".web_header_mb_"+i).css("width", "200");
        });

        $(".web_header_mb_"+i).mouseout(function () 
        {
            $(".web_header_mb_"+i).css("width", "300");
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb_1"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb_2"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb_3"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb_4"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb_5"></div>
```

When start show different `id`s in the bucle but when I do a `mouseover`, there's no change to the size.

Comment: Rather than a for loop, I think this would be a lot cleaner with a css class or two, reducing the javascript to a single line or so.

Comment: I removed the new code you added, because you asked a **new question**. Please post it as a new question. You can still [find the code in the revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11783427/revisions).

Comment: ah ok i think i can put something more and continue the post ok , i´ll create new post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work**

The reason your code doesn't work is this:

`i` will have the correct value for code that is executed immediately (e.g. the `show` and `hover` calls). But, because of the way JavaScript works, this doesn't work for callback (such as the one you give to `hover`). JavaScript will remember the **variable**, not the **value** of the variable at the time the callback was provided. The callback won't be called until *after the loop is completed*. That's why in the callbacks `i` will always be **5**, because that was `i`'s last value.

You can read more about that here: [Closures (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Also, be aware that `id`'s **must** be unique. You can't give the `id` "menu" to five different elements; that's what classes are for. In other words: you've got `id` and `class` backwards in your code.

**How to make it work**

The easiest way to circumvent the closure "problem" is to use `$(this)` inside the callback functions. In jQuery, the `this` keyword inside a callback function always points to the object which triggered the event. By using `$(this)` you have exactly the right jQuery object, without any fuss:

```
for (i=1; i<=menu_h_number; i++)
{
    var currentItem = $(".web_header_mb_" + i);

    currentItem
        .show(1000)
        .css("background", "#FF0000");
        .hover(
            function() { // mouseenter
                $(this).css("width", 200);    // <--
            },
            function() { // mouseleave
                $(this).css("width", 300);    // <--
            });
}
```

Another thing I did in the code above is *buffer* the jQuery object in a local variable (`currentItem`). This makes your code faster, because you only have to look up the element once (instead of 6 times, in this case). You should do this as much as possible.

Also, as you can see, the [`hover` function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) isn't just for the `mouseover` event. You can give it callbacks to handle both `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

One other thing you could do, as others have already suggested, is use a single class instead of 5 different classes. The jQuery function (`$()`) will actually return a **collection** if the query matches more than one object.

So, given the following HTML:

```
<div class="menu web_header_mb"></div>
<div class="menu web_header_mb"></div>
<div class="menu web_header_mb"></div>
<div class="menu web_header_mb"></div>
<div class="menu web_header_mb"></div>
```

You could use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), like this:

```
$(".menu.web_header_mb").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .show(1000)
        .css("background", "#FF0000");
        .hover(
            function() { // mouseenter
                $(this).css("width", 200);
            },
            function() { // mouseleave
                $(this).css("width", 300);
            });
});
```

Or even this:

```
$(".menu.web_header_mb").
    .show(1000)
    .css("background", "#FF0000");
    .hover(
        function() { // mouseenter
            $(this).css("width", 200);
        },
        function() { // mouseleave
            $(this).css("width", 300);
        });
```

That last one works because [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) all work on jQuery *collections* (as well as single jQuery objects). Neat, huh?

Comment: yes true with $(this) works perfectly , until of this i create function with name and call function and for that works until but now i use this and if no use $(this) no works and right all time when i put alert() i see the value for i=5 always , now works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
$(function(){

    var menu_h_number=5;

    for (var i=1; i <= menu_h_number;i++) {
        $(".web_header_mb_"+i).show(1000)
                              .css("background","#FF0000")
                              .mouseover(function () {
                                  $(this).css("width","200");
                              })
                              .mouseout(function () {
                                  $(this).css("width","300");
                              });
    }
});
```

Also available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPVwN/)

Answer (score 1):

Its because the i variable is not in scope or  has the latest value when the hover code is executed.  Instead use this variable.

Fyi: 
1. your div tag are having same ID but different classname. Instead, make them same class and different ID. Than you can make use of jQuery.each function very nicely.

1. hover function can have 2 arguments, first for mousein and second for mouseout. That way you can concise your code

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.hover() actually takes two arguements, mouse in and mouse out.

```
$(".web_header_mb_"+i).hover(
function ()  { $(this).css("width","200px") }, 
function ()  { $(this).css("width","300px") }
);
```

Actually, looking at the code, that's not really a good way of doing it.  Here try it this way: Gave all the divs the same class instead iterating with a for loop, and use the $.each to give the desired events.

```
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb"></div>
<div id="menu" class="web_header_mb"></div>

$.each(".web_header_mb", function (){
  $(this).hover(
   function ()  { $(this).css("width","200px") }, 
   function ()  { $(this).css("width","300px") }
  );
});
```

Comment: I modificate the code for rollover menu mouover and detect par or impar elements you can see , the question now it´s how i can create effect over background

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to loop over elements, jQuery does that for you if you just figure out the selector.

Try matching every element that has a class that starts with `web_header_mb_` and then just remove elements that you don't want. If they have the right index you can `:lt(5)` or `slice(0,5)`, otherwise you'll have to filter them based on the last character of the class. You can also chain methods, no need to call the selector every time :

```
$("[class^='web_header_mb_']").filter(function() {
    var C = $(this).prop('class'); 
        C = C.charAt(C.length-1);
    return (C==1||C==2||C==3||C==4||C==5);
}).show(1000)
  .css("background","#FF0000")
  .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).css('width', e.type==='mouseenter'?'200':300);
});
```

or

```
$("[class^='web_header_mb_']:lt(5)").show(1000)
    .css("background","#FF0000")
    .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
       $(this).css('width', e.type==='mouseenter'?'200':300);
});
```